# Parse data for a dynamic URL

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I am working on creating a link to help documents. The link is set up to get the URL string (server info) and then append the version string onto the end of it.

The problem that I am having is that we keep track of our version using a 4 digit system with each digit having a specific meaning, but the links to the help documents only use the first 3 digits.

Is there a way to edit the version# that I am getting so that it only includes the first 3 digits when I add it to the URL? 
example: 
Version # 2.4.5.345 
URL: ServerURLHere/version-2.4.5

This is getting the version #

```
private void SetApplicationVersion()
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var versionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
        Application["__application_version__"] = versionInfo.FileVersion;
    }
```

This sets the first part of the URL

```
<add key="Help_URL" value="ServerURLHere/version-" />
```

This creates the URL that is used. This is where I am wondering if it is possible to limit the application version to a 3 digit set instead of using all 4.

```
var help = new Help({ Help_URL: '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Help_URL"]' + '@HttpContext.Current.Application["__application_version__"]' });
```

Comment: and why can't you do a sub string on the `versionInfo.FileVersion` to pull back the correct characters you need...

Comment: wow. I can't believe I didn't think of that. That worked and was extremely simple. Thank you

Comment: sometimes it's the simplest things that can save your life in regards to coding glad it was a workable suggestion.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your concern is possible version numbers with more than one digit (2.42.1045 for example), you can use split and concat to be sure you'll grab the full version:

```
string version = "2.42.1045.3434";
string[] proc = version.Split('.');
version = string.Concat(proc[0], ".", proc[1], ".", proc[2]);
Console.Write(version);
```

Another alternative is to use Substring and LastIndexOf:

```
version = "2.42.1045.3434";            
Console.Write(version.Substring(0, version.LastIndexOf('.')));
```